# Machine does not power up with keyboard or [wireless] mouse movement

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, power-management, lenovo

This machine is Lenovo Desktop H535 running Ubuntu 20.04 with Logitech K360 wireless mouse.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Or is it Windows?

Comment: Apologies;   using Ubuntu 20.04 ,,,,,,,,, Interestingly enough it happened again after  an upgrade/update